# Angular remove object from array search for key and value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to remove an entry from an array by searching for the id value.

The data looks like this:

```
data = [ { "id": "02" }, { "id": "03" } ];
```

And I need a method like:

```
remove(keyValue) {
    // do something here
}
```

Usage example:

```
remove('02');
```

Then it would search the id key with value "02" and remove the data so it would remove like this:

```
data = [ { "id": "03" } ];
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `data.filter(elem => elem['id'] !== keyValue)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works if key is "id", and if you are sure there won't be repeated values:

```js
var data = [ { "id": "02" }, { "id": "03" } ];

function removeVal(value) {
  var removeIndex = -1;
  data.forEach((obj, index) => {
    if (obj.id === value) {
      removeIndex = index;
    }
  });
  data.splice(removeIndex, 1);
  console.log(data);
}

removeVal("02");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-g3gty2

where the method remove accepts the initial array, the key and the value to remove.

```
function remove(data: any[], key: string, value: any) {
  return data.filter(d => d[key] !== value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Typescript remove quotes from property names.

```
data = [ { id: "02" }, { id: "03" } ];
```

You can use `findIndex` function to get the index of specific element. After you got the index you can delete the element with `splice` function.

```js
remove(keyValue: String) {
 let objectIndex = this.data.findIndex(e => e.id == keyValue); 

 if(objectIndex != -1) {
  this.data.splice(objectIndex, 1); // Remove one element from array
 }

}
```